# Operation must use an updatable query error In setup

Tags: winforms

Unhandled exception has occurred while I am trying to create setup the connection string is not working.

Comment: So we have a winforms tag, but the question is about an exception to do with a "connection string", and no code is included. Do you seriously think it's possible to answer this question without more information? It's exactly the same as "hey, my code doesn't work. Help".

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you've really provided is an error message with very little supporting detail. I put your error message into Google for you and found this link:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175168

Comment: Actually the error is new for me as even I am a newbie and when I am done with the setup the error occurred while I am entering any data.

Comment: Was the Microsoft support page I linked you to helpful at all?

Comment: Tried but the problem is the same